# How to notify all subscriber classes about a raised event in one class?

Tags: c#, .net, events, delegates, notify

I am learning how to use events around classes to notify 2 classes if an even occurs in one class. I have created the following.

```
namespace TestConsole
{
    class Program : Form
    {
        public event EventHandler Something;
        public Program()
        {
            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.Parent = this;
            btn.Text = "Click Me.!";
            btn.Location = new Point(100, 100);
            btn.Click += Btn_Click;
            Something += HandleThis;
        }

        private void Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            Something(this,null);
        }
        private void HandleThis(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("From Main: Something typed");
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Application.Run(new Program());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    class One
    {
        One()
        {
            Program SubscriberObj = new Program();
            SubscriberObj.Something += HandleEvent;
        }

        private void HandleEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("From One: Something typed");
        }
    }

    class Two
    {
        Two()
        {
            Program SubscriberObj = new Program();
            SubscriberObj.Something += HandleEvent;
        }

        private void HandleEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("From Two: Something typed");
        }

    }

}
```

I want the HandleEvent method of both Class one and Two to be triggered once the button is clicked. But I am seeing event raised in Program class only. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You do not create an instance of `One` and `Two`. Therefore, no class will register for this event. Also, you create new instances of `program` in `One` and `Two`. But you need the same instance in which the event is fired. You must pass the instance of `program` in the constructor. You should also always check if the handler is null when the event gets fired.

```
    EventHandler handler = Something;
    handler?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
```

This code is equivalent to:

```
    EventHandler handler = Something;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
    }
```